# Unable to locate package bugzilla3

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, bugzilla

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 and am trying to install bugzilla3. I did:

```
sudo apt-get install bugzilla3
```

and I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package bugzilla3
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to add one of the repositories listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bugzilla&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

This is what I added:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
```

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla3 isn't in your repos, apparently. Try changing them, updating them, etc. I recommend using Synaptic, typing in a part of the package name, and seeing what comes up to be sure you have the name right. Muon works too, I used it to check just now.

Comment: Yep, I ended up adding the Lucid repository and I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Open your terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try again.